# Increasing the value of a bounty after setting it

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, bounties

Since 100-rep does not attract enough attention, I would like to increase the value of the bounty I've placed on my question, [LaTeX equations in Ubuntu’s MediaWiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610842/latex-equations-in-ubuntus-mediawiki).

Can you increase the value of a bounty after setting it?

Comment: Original version wasn't quite proposing a feature-request. Stocker's answer floats some.

Comment: @Random I've updated my answer to be both a feature request and an answer; I'm smooth like that.

Answer (score 10):

#### Answer

To answer your question, no you can not change the bounty after offering it.  Your options are to :

- Keep modifying your question every day of the bounty with new things you've tried to keep it active
- Allow it to run out; award the bounty and re-ask with new question

Also, I don't think your problem is solely the bounty you offered.  You also offered it in a very much *niche* subject.  However, the bounty system could use extension in cases like yours.

---

**Feature Request**

- [Allow asker increase the bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26731/raise-bounty-upon-setting) after *x* days if they don't receive any new upvoted answers
- Allow them to extend it for another 7 days for the same reason

Please treat these as separate feature requests.

Comment: But at least one half of that is a dupe feature-request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26731/raise-bounty-upon-setting

Comment: @random: Thanks! I added that link.

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

This is effectively completed, because

- bounty system is no longer tied to accepting an answer in any way
- you can issue multiple bounties on your question if necessary