# Is it possible to upgrade the bounty feature?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Raise bounty upon setting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26731/raise-bounty-upon-setting)

Maybe some of you will agree with me on this one but bounty system needs some kind of upgrade. I'd recommend following:

1. If you don't get your answer, maybe you should be able to increase bounty, double it or something
2. If the automatically accepted answer isn't the correct answer, then we should have a possibility to decrease the bounty.

Comment: Ok the downvote, care to explain?

Comment: @comrade I didn't downvote you (I upvoted, in fact, because I like the first suggestion) but on Meta, voting habits are a bit different. Downvotes are seen as an expression of disagreement, and don't have the perceived weight they have on SO.

Comment: And some downvote when someone whines about a previous downvote

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26731/raise-bounty-upon-setting

Comment: @Downvoter I don't whine. Here is the definition `http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Awhine`, I certainly did no such thing. I'm just interested why, unless you got nothing to do then open every post and downvote, I bet that is super fun for you. Hence the chosen nick I guess.

Comment: @John Smithers thats a valid point for downvoitng

Comment: @Downvoter: "out of courtesy" a person who downvotes should also care to explain the reason why they did it.. =)

Comment: @Madi - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes

Comment: @Madi, some people agree with that, some don't

Comment: @c0mrade: It's rather a valid point for *closing*. Btw, the definition of 'whining' on meta is somewhat skewed, to say the least.

Comment: Should people who upvote also be expected to explain every upvote?

Comment: @fretje "It's rather a valid point for closing" - couldn't agree more

Comment: @random I don't know if they are to be expected, but I almost always do it, 90 % of the time, if nothing I say something like "good point +1, like it" or whatever.. And NO, no one should be expected to do anything, I'm just asking could you provide an explanation so that I can improve the question, or delete it or whatever, I'm not angry or anything like that, I just ask for exp. if I can't get one that is totally acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first suggestion has some merit, the handling of an ending bounty that had no or no satisfying response is not optimal at the moment.

I think it should be made possible to set a second bounty on a question after the first one has run out (with no refunds on the first bounty, though). A question becoming un-bountyable and un-acceptable after a bounty has run out with no auto-accepted answer is a terrible condition IMO. (Discussion [**here**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=bounty+accept).)

The second suggestion I'm against. If I put up a bounty, I have to pay it, period. If you don't get an answer that matches your expectations, it's your risk.-

Comment: @Pekka "The second suggestion I'm against. If I put up a bounty, I have to pay it, period. If you don't get an answer that matches your expectations, it's your risk.-" Valid point for now, I just think that the whole bounty system needs major overhaul, yes you should pay for answer but if you get a crappy one you shouldn't, at least to refund some of your points .. for now its not possible but it needs to be addressed sooner or later. I personally am not prone  to bounty questions because of this..

Comment: @c0mrade I see your point but disagree. The bounty system is very simple at the moment, I'm against complicating it. (and I have spent 2,250 rep on bounties this year alone.)

Comment: I'm not necessarily for making it complicated, I also like to think that less is more, but some users get to your bounty by just writing "can I get the bounty" and some people like the idea of humor about that and vote it up, ending up wining that user some points whatever, the points don't matter, but not getting the answer does and on top of that you loose some of your rep points which you could use for other bounty, I'm talking for people who have few hundred points ..

Comment: @c0mrade The solution to that is simple: Keep track of your bounties, and if there are only B.S. answers, award it to yourself. It's a perfectly valid practice as far as I'm aware, because you lose the points in any case.