# Option to increase bounty?

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I think it would be nice to be able to increase an active bounty. A user might initially offer 100 but if it doesn't get any new answers, then the user should have the option to increase it.

Comment: Note: this is NOT a duplicate of [Raise bounty later?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26731/raise-bounty-later) as the other one is about starting a new bounty after the first is already done, while this one here is for raising it while the bounty is still active, and  those are different requests.

Comment: The possibility to increase the bounty will be great.