# How to increase the bounty on someone else's question

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Raise bounty later?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26731/raise-bounty-later)

I put a bounty of 50 points on someone else's question, but now I think that's not enough and I can't find an option for increasing that bounty.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can't - only put another bounty on later.

Comment: It's indirectly possible using the same method as [increasing bounties on your own questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26731/raise-bounty-later). Wait for the bounty to elapse (and make sure you award it), and then just add a new bounty afterwards. Otherwise, there's no method to increase an already active bounty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Grace Note - but I don't see how this is a duplicate of that other question, since the answer to that is "you can now!", but to my specific question the answer appears to be "you can't".