# Opened a bounty for lack of attention, now I want to increase the bounty because answers lack quality

Tags: feature-request, bounties, feedback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Raise bounty later?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26731/raise-bounty-later)

I opened a small bounty (50) because my question didn't get much attention.

It worked, and now I have three answers that are not correct (despite each of them having two upvotes). I explained in the comments why they are not right.

Now I want to increase the bounty because answers lack quality.

I think people would rather increase the 'bet' to extend the period than to see the bounty going to a bad answer. I would.

PS: OK, this is not a question per-se, but the email warning me about the bounty deadline pointed me here with the word "feedback" linked, so I'm giving it.

Edit: and why not use this to freeload some more attention to the question? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176516/why-does-android-ignore-my-etc-hosts-change-in-the-browser

Comment: Why are you telling us all of this? Is there a question you have for us, or can you ask one? Otherwise, I'm not sure this is an appropriate way to get positive attention for your question. Creative? Yes. Appropriate... probably not ;)

Comment: @jmort253 I explained why i wrote it here in the "PS", also, only added the original question here as an afterthough, after i wrote the feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a bigger bounty isn't going to give you *fewer* poor answers, you'll almost certainly get more crappy answers just hoping for a bounty-by-default.

<s>If you don't want the bounty to be automatically awarded to a poor answer, self-answer saying so and award yourself the bounty. You won't get the rep back, of course, but you won't be rewarding poor answers.</s> At one point you could, but now [you can't even just award yourself the bounty to keep it from being awarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105035).

Simply keeping the bounty going as it is isn't an option, but I do think it's an interesting idea to offer the option of rolling the bounty over if you offer a new bounty during the grace period. Most likely not going to happen though, there have already been a great many posts offering complaints and suggestions along those lines.

Comment: I don't think you can award a bounty to yourself...

Comment: @YannisRizos I'm fairly certain you can, you just don't get the rep back. Perhaps the OP will try and let us know for sure.

Comment: [*"We disabled that option because it led to confusion, and is against the 'spirit' of bounties."*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105035/134300)

Comment: that would still be the better option against 'i just did a google search and put the first answer here for 50% of the bounty'

Answer (score 5):

You can't change an active bounty after offering it. Besides technical complications, I imagine it would be unfair to the users contributing answers at the time the original bounty was offered, because by changing it you're telling users that their once-eligible answers are no longer acceptable, thus wasting their effort in a way.

The typical way of handling this is to either award the bounty now or wait for it to be automatically awarded at 50% to any of the eligible answers, at least for their effort (see [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)), then offer another bounty with the higher amount of your choosing, and with the "Improve details" reason.

Comment: This argument really doesn't hold up, as the OP may also post additional information to the initial question while trying to solve the issue. As such, the direction of the question could very possibly change making any user contributions, in some ways, potentially obsolete. I have seen countless posts that offer a wide array of answers and as the OP posts updates and additional info in an effort to resolve the problem, the solution ends up being very different than the suggestions first offered. I think the Bounty concept is somewhat miss construed, cont'd

Comment: Does Bounty only offer greater visibility? OR could it be enticement to pull higher quality answers, from more highly qualified professionals? Sometimes any ideas toward solving an issue can be helpful, but where increased bounty points might be available, there seems to be a greater chance that higher quality answers maybe offered, and yes perhaps more lower quality, but as I mentioned, any ideas may still be helpful. So it looks to be a win win, regardless, should the bounty be able to be increased