# Why can't I increase to an outstanding bounty?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties

A friendly user placed a bounty on a question of mine:

[Is there really no version of realloc() supporting alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45503469/1593077)

The thing is, it's a pretty small bounty, and I want to augment it a bit. It doesn't seem I have an option of doing that; why?

Comment: Indeed it would be nice if it could be edited to add more points to the bounty.

Comment: Because you can add another bounty after the current one expires, drawing *even more* attention to your question?

Comment: This feature request was already asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54291/323179) and the answer is you can, if you wait until the first bounty has ended.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Does that lead to too much bounty inflation? ... Oh, well, I guess I can live with that answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo: Well, that was about raising your own bounty, this is about raising somebody else's. But whatevs.

Comment: I think it would be wise to also preface this question with https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Answer (score 1):

A bounty is to attract attention. It shows up no matter how much the bounty.

If it doesn't get the attention needed, you can put your bounty on once that one expires, adding to the length of time the question is highlighted.

Comment: So why have different bounty amounts to begin with?

Comment: So you can decide how much you think it is worth. I sometimes have put on the minimum, sometimes thousands.

Comment: But I think it's worth more than the person who put the bounty...

Comment: So once that one finishes, you can put in as much as you like.

Comment: More information available in the the Help Center: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty